# Analytic function expansion with Riemann Zeta coefficients.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Anyone have any ideas of how to progress with this sum? $$ \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(j)}(a)}{j!} \left(\zeta(-(j-1)e^{i \pi t}) -   \dfrac{1}{(j-1)e^{i \pi t} + 1}  \right).$$ $f(x) \in O(x)$ as $x \to \infty$, and it is analytic, $t \in (0,1)$.

If anyone is wondering how I arrived at this series, I used the Euler-Maclaurin expansion for an integral involving f and the Bernoulli numbers gave me the zeta function.

I was thinking if I could express this properly as some sort of Mellin transform, maybe I could use something like Ramujan's master theorem so that I could solve it for any such $f$.

Would appreciate any feedback or ideas.

Comment: The context isn't enough, or at least for me. What exactly led you to this sum? What function did you substitute in the Euler-Maclaurin formula?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is the original form for the Euler-Maclaurin summation. $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}} \frac{B^{+}_{n}}{n!}  \left( \frac{d^{n-1}}{ds^{n-1}}  (\frac{f( ({\frac{s}{k})^{e^{i \pi t}}}+ a) - f(a)}{(\frac{s}{k})^{e^{i \pi t}}})\rvert_{s = k}   -  \frac{d^{n-1}}{ds^{n-1}}  (\frac{f( ({\frac{s}{k})^{e^{i \pi t}}}+ a) - f(a)}{(\frac{s}{k})^{e^{i \pi t}}})\rvert_{s = 0}  \right)\, $

Comment: This seems like a random combination of functions, but apparently, the function getting differentiated looks reminds me of the definition of the derivative. Maybe that helps with solving the second derivative.

Comment: Well without the derivation I definitely understand how it looks random haha. The reason it's reminding you of the definition of the derivative is because it is the difference quotient of the given analytic function.